# Audio output settings: Fontpanel and Backpanel audio at the same time

Tags: sound, headphones

I have Ubuntu 17.10 on my PC. I have a set of speakers always connected to line out in the back of PC and I want to connect my headphones all the times to the front panel. So whenever I want to switch to headphone I simply change the audio output in the settings. However, when I plug the headphone to the front panel the back panel line out is gone from output list in setting.

How can I make Ubuntu to show both audio outputs when the headphone is connected?

Here is the screen shot when headphone is not connected
[image: Headphone is not connected]

When headphone is connected:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using "Pulse audio volume control" ([pavucontrol](http://alloutput.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/pavucontrol-output-devices.png)) , you will have more controls, like speaker/headphone ports, or  setting a default output.
Install command:
 `sudo apt install pavucontrol`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Pulse Audio provide great control. However, the problem still exist. When I plug the headphone, the Pulse audio shows the line out (back panel) as Unplugged.

Comment: alsamixer (run it in a terminal) as a "automute" setting, you can try to disable this  (using arrow keys ).

Comment: I already this, the problem with removing automute is that it will make  the sound to be played on both speaker and headphone in the same time. I do not have control over them